# The symbol of a pseudifferential operator: how to reconstruct the symbol from an operator?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform, distribution-theory, pseudo-differential-operators

To simplify let us assume that $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set. Let $P$ be a (scalar) psuedodifferential operator of order $d$ and $p$ be its symbol. Therefore it may be expressed as follows: 
$Pf(x)=\int e^{ix \xi}p(x,\xi)\hat{f}(\xi)d\xi$ where $f \in C^{\infty}_c(U)$ is a smooth function with compact support. The fact that $P$ is of order $d$ imposes some growth condition on the function $p$.

> Why the symbol may be reconstructed as $p(x,\xi)=e^{-ix \xi}P(e^{ix \xi})$.

This should be simple but I have a problem in understanding this formula since most likely it should interpreted in the distributional sense. I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that
\begin{align}
\widehat{e^{ix\eta}}(\xi) = \int dx\ e^{-ix(\xi-\eta)} = \delta(\xi-\eta)
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
P(e^{ix\eta})(x, \eta) =&\ \int d\xi\ e^{ix \xi} p(x, \xi)\ \widehat{e^{iy\eta}}(\xi)\\
=&\  \int d\xi\ e^{ix\xi}p(x, \xi) \delta(\xi-\eta)= e^{ix\eta}p(x, \eta).
\end{align}
Finally, we see that
\begin{align}
e^{-ix\eta}P(e^{ix\eta}) = p(x, \eta).
\end{align}